# Web api cannot start an exe process C#

Tags: c#, process, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a web api hosted in Windows Server 2012 r2. On startup this api starts a third party exe file using the following code snippet:

```
_service = new Process()
            {
                StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
                {
                    FileName = "file.exe",
                    Arguments = "-C config.xml",
                    WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
                    LoadUserProfile = true,
                    WorkingDirectory = "C:\TestFolder",
                    CreateNoWindow = true
                }
            };

_service.Start()
```

It works fine on my local machine, but after I deployed it on server, it hangs. I tried setting Load User Profile = true for the app pool but that didn't help. Also tried setting the app pool for 32 bit but that didn't work either. Any idea?

Comment: "it hangs." is unlikely. What does your error handling code look like?

Comment: Log the exception...   Is it your own server?  If not in all probability you don't have permission to launch an exe or write to "c:\TestFolder".   And you might want to escape the backslash before TestFolder...  ;-)

Comment: If you have access to the server look at the IIS -> sites -> yourWebServer ->right click ->edit permissions -> seurity -> look if the user who the application runs under its identity listed in the Group or User names box and check which permissions he has. In many cases problem lies there.

Answer (score 0):

I am putting this here for future reference. It turns out since I downloaded the exe file, the system was prompting for a "confirmation" to run the executables. That's why it was "hanging" for a user response.

The funny thing is it was only happening when I was trying to run the process using IIS. I wrote a console application to test it out and the process started just fine.

The way I fixed it was I changed the process WindowStyle to Normal which prompted for the Confirmation Dialogue. After it popped up I unchecked the "Always ask for this file before running", and that fixed the issue.

I wonder if tehre's a way to "introduce" an exe to system so it doesn't even ask for the confirmation.